# executing command after breakpoint with Windbg doesn't work?

Tags: window, kernel, windbg

I am using a simple command like this :

```
bp KernelFunctionAddress "dd esp L1;g"
```

but when the breakpoint is hit I get this :

Break

```
instruction exception - code 80000003 (first chance)
nt!KernelFunction:
87975cd0 8bff            mov     edi,edi
```

why is this happening? why the command is not getting executed after breakpoint is hit? I just simply want to dump the value of the esp and do a g command so it doesn't stop, but its not working?

assume KernelFunction is a function in the kernel, it doesn't matter what function. I'm also using windbg preview

when I also type .sxcmds nothing happens :

```
0: kd> .sxcmds 

0: kd> bl
     0 e Disable Clear  86c20615     0001 (0001)  "dd esp L1;g"

0: kd> g
Break instruction exception - code 80000003 (first chance)
storport!RaDriverScsiIrp:
86c20615 8bff            mov     edi,edi
```

Comment: What happens if you just use something like `bp KernelFunctionAddress ".echotime;gc"`

Comment: In user mode, it will say "Breakpoint 2 hit", not "code 80000003", but may be different in kernel mode. Are you sure the breakpoint is really hit or could it be something else?

Comment: @ThomasWeller yes it hits the breakpoint in the start of the function, but nothing gets printed and it doesn't execute the g command, so the syntax of my command is correct right?

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers same thing, nothing special gets printed and it doesn't continue execution it stops at the address : Break instruction exception - code 80000003 (first chance)
89623e62 8bff           mov edi,edi

Comment: type .sxcmds and see if any first chance is handled for bp

Comment: @blabb when I type .sxcmds nothing happens! I provided the output in the edited question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not sure why ?
it should work  are you mixing up a x64 windbg on a x86 target or vice versa does wow come into play

EDIT
added a kernel session with windbg preview  winx host and target (all x64)

**host windows and windbg preview version**

```
PS C:\> Get-ComputerInfo -Property WindowsBuildLabEx,OsVersion,OsBuildNumber  
WindowsBuildLabEx                         OsVersion  OsBuildNumber
-----------------                         ---------  -------------
18362.1.amd64fre.19h1_release.190318-1202 10.0.18363 18363

PS C:\> (Get-AppPackage -Name Microsoft.windbg ).Version  
1.2001.2001.0
```

**Target and Transport**

```
0: kd> vertarget
Windows 10 Kernel Version 17763 MP (2 procs) Free x64
17763.1.amd64fre.rs5_release.180914-1434

0: kd> dx Debugger.Sessions
Debugger.Sessions                
    [0x0]            : Remote KD: KdSrv:Server=@{<Local>},Trans=@{COM:Port=\\.\pipe\vmwpipe,Baud=115200,Pipe,Timeout=4000,Resets=2}
```

**breakpoint with condition on an arbitrary kernel Function**

```
0: kd> bl
     0 e Disable Clear  fffff801`3ecea760     0001 (0001) nt!NtQueryDirectoryFile "dpp @rsp+50 l1;dt nt!_unicode_string poi(@rsp+50);.echo ===========;gc"
```

**Explanation Of Bp and Condition**

*NtQueryDirectoryFile is prototyped as*

```
__kernel_entry NTSYSCALLAPI NTSTATUS NtQueryDirectoryFile(
  HANDLE                 FileHandle,            == @rcx
  HANDLE                 Event,                 == @rdx
  PIO_APC_ROUTINE        ApcRoutine,            == @r8
  PVOID                  ApcContext,            == @r9
  PIO_STATUS_BLOCK       IoStatusBlock,         == [rsp+28]
  PVOID                  FileInformation,       == [rsp+30]
  ULONG                  Length,                == [rsp+38]
  FILE_INFORMATION_CLASS FileInformationClass,  == [rsp+40]
  BOOLEAN                ReturnSingleEntry,     == [rsp+48]
  PUNICODE_STRING        FileName,              == [rsp+50]  <==>  printing this
  BOOLEAN                RestartScan            == [rsp+58]
);
```

result

```
0: kd> g
fffffd0e`2ca835d8  ffff8e07`848f9628 00000000`00160016
 "diagwrn.xml"
   +0x000 Length           : 0x16
   +0x002 MaximumLength    : 0x16
   +0x008 Buffer           : 0xffff8e07`849d37f6  "diagwrn.xml"
===========
fffffd0e`2c0c05d8  ffff8e07`848f9628 00000000`00140014
 "SRUtmp.log"
   +0x000 Length           : 0x14
   +0x002 MaximumLength    : 0x14
   +0x008 Buffer           : 0xffff8e07`849d37ea  "SRUtmp.log"
===========
fffffd0e`2ca835d8  ffff8e07`848fc528 00000000`001a001a
 "EventStore.db"
   +0x000 Length           : 0x1a
   +0x002 MaximumLength    : 0x1a
   +0x008 Buffer           : 0xffff8e07`84a6ca60  "EventStore.db"
===========
fffffd0e`2c1df5d8  ffff8e07`848fc528 00000000`00100010
 "data.dat"
   +0x000 Length           : 0x10
   +0x002 MaximumLength    : 0x10
   +0x008 Buffer           : 0xffff8e07`7f0877fe  "data.dat"
===========
fffffd0e`2c66f898  ffff8e07`82f81548 00000000`006c006c
 "ScreenOnPowerStudyTraceSession-2020-07-05-12-01-44.etl"
   +0x000 Length           : 0x6c
   +0x002 MaximumLength    : 0x6c
   +0x008 Buffer           : 0xffff8e07`7f6cdb9a  "ScreenOnPowerStudyTraceSession-2020-07-05-12-01-44.etl"
===========
```

**END OF EDIT**

I just ran an arbitrary test on an usermode x64 binary with an arbitrary function on an x64 on classic x64 windbg 18362 winx it seems to work correctly

DispatchMessage  windows message struct __TAGMSG  which contains the WM_xxx #defines

```
0:005> bl
     0 e Disable Clear  00007ffe`2e4f5410     0001 (0001)  0:**** USER32!DispatchMessageW ".echotime;.echo====================;dd @rcx l4;gc"
0:005> g
Debugger (not debuggee) time: Sat Jul  4 00:26:34.254 2020 
====================
0000001d`7675d6b0  00140494 00000000 00000113 00000000
Debugger (not debuggee) time: Sat Jul  4 00:26:35.004 2020 
====================
0000001d`7675d6b0  001c0628 00000000 00000060 00000000
Debugger (not debuggee) time: Sat Jul  4 00:26:49.047 2020 
====================
0000001d`7675d6b0  001606ac 00000000 0000000f 00000000
Debugger (not debuggee) time: Sat Jul  4 00:26:49.063 2020 
====================
0000001d`7675d6b0  000d06a6 00000000 00000118 00000000
Debugger (not debuggee) time: Sat Jul  4 00:26:50.047 2020 
====================
0000001d`7675d6b0  000d06a6 00000000 00000118 00000000
Debugger (not debuggee) time: Sat Jul  4 00:26:51.047 2020 
====================
0000001d`7675d6b0  001c0628 00000000 00000060 00000000
Debugger (not debuggee) time: Sat Jul  4 00:26:51.094 2020 
====================
0000001d`7675d6b0  001c0628 00000000 00000060 00000000
Debugger (not debuggee) time: Sat Jul  4 00:26:51.094 2020 
====================
0000001d`7675d6b0  001606ac 00000000 0000000f 00000000
Debugger (not debuggee) time: Sat Jul  4 00:26:51.188 2020 
====================
(2070.20e0): Break instruction exception - code 80000003 (first chance)
ntdll!DbgBreakPoint:    00007ffe`2fd3faa0 cc              int     3
```